# How i get mongo DB data by searching using field name where field's value is the prefix of given value?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Suppose, I have inserted like:

```
db.test.insert([
{"name":"hello_wrold"},
{"name":"hello_w"},
{"name":"hell"},
{"name":"helo"}
]);
```

I want to search the documents which contain the prefix of "hello_world" in name field.

**For this the expected output is:**

```
   [
    {"name":"hello_wrold"},
    {"name":"hello_w"},
    {"name":"hell"}
   ]
```

In spring-boot application how i implement this?

Comment: How do you define "prefix"? Should "help" match? or "Helvetica" or "harrow"?

Comment: I have hello_world, i want which value match as a prefix of hello_world, here, 'hello_world', 'hello_w', 'hello' are the prefix of 'hello_world'.